# Count non empty fields in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this simple MYSQL table1:

```
id
 1
 2
 3
```

AND this table2:

```
 id | question | answer
  1 |  how     | 
  2 |  are     | fine
  3 |  you     | ok
```

And this simple query:

```
SELECT table1.id,COUNT(answer NOT NULL) FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2
       ON table1.id = table2.id
```

I want to count non empty answer fields. I tried NOT NULL but it's not working as the `answer` column is `NOT NULL` and where is not applicable as it will lead the main query to return nothing

Comment: are you having group by clause in your query ?

Comment: No no need for group i think

Comment: Why are you selecting the id then?

Comment: without group by i think your query is not possible..!!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [CHAR_LENGTH(str)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) function to check length of value.
Use below query :

```
SELECT COUNT(answer) FROM table WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(answer)>0;
```

From [Reference Doc.](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-character_length-function.php)

**EDIT :**
You may try this query :

```
SELECT COUNT(answer) FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2
       ON table1.id = table2.id AND CHAR_LENGTH(table2.answer)>0
```

Comment: sorry this select is actually a LEFT JOIN but i'm simplifying the query for the sake of the question. So if I put a WHERE clause it will lead to no result

Comment: POST your query with LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @JavaDev, you need to get rid of the NOT NULL, COUNT(expr) counts 1 for every not null expr. NOT NULL converts the NULL answers into BOOLEANs, so NULL answers will be counted.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, to capture everything that is blank:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table
where answer IS NOT NULL or answer <>''
```

That should grab and count any row that has any value in "answer".

Or, if there is a join:

```
SELECT     table1.count(id), table2.question
FROM         table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      tabel1 ON table1.id = table2.id
GROUP BY table1.id,table2.question
HAVING      (table2.answer <> '') OR (table2.answer IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: sorry this select is actually a LEFT JOIN but i'm simplifying the query for the sake of the question. So if I put a WHERE clause it will lead to no result

Comment: Use HAVING then.  That's what that's used for.

Comment: can you please explain more as I have never heard of having

Comment: Do not use HAVING, that is not what HAVING is for, HAVING is for filtering GROUPs.

Comment: Yes - I know.  And I've added that to my answer to show that.  His original post didn't say anything about a join, or extra columns.  No need for a group.  But if there is a join, presumably there will be more columns.

Comment: Why are you suddenly introducing GROUPS into a query that doesn't need them?

Comment: It does need them if there are more columns than just the initial count.

Comment: Oops, didn't see the extra column

Comment: I still think HAVING is not necessary here, I don't think the GROUPs are supposd to be filtered out, just the rows in them.

Comment: You're probably right.  But this gives a good overview for how to handle all those situations.

Answer (score 0):

Just count Number of rows having NULL answers!

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table /* COUNT(1) will go on counting rows frequncy*/
where answer IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: sorry this select is actually a LEFT JOIN but i'm simplifying the query for the sake of the question. So if I put a WHERE clause it will lead to no result

Answer (score 0):

If the answer column is not nullable then `IS NOT NULL` will return all the rows. What you want is "is not empty string":

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE answer <> "";
```

If answer is nullable then you can check for both conditions:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE answer IS NOT NULL AND answer <> "";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT COUNT(t2.answer) count
     FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
       ON t2.id = t1.id
      AND t2.answer != ''
```

OR

```
   SELECT t1.id, COUNT(t2.answer) count
     FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
       ON t2.id = t1.id
      AND t2.answer != ''
 GROUP BY t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this  `SUM(CHAR_LENGTH((answer))/CHAR_LENGTH((answer)))` formula to count non empty answer fields.

```
SELECT table1.id, SUM(CHAR_LENGTH((answer))/CHAR_LENGTH((answer))) FROM table1
```

`LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id`

Answer (score 0):

Count each of your columns:

```
SELECT count(`id`) + count(`personal_id`) + count(`f_name`) + ... 
FROM `detail_members` WHERE `personal_id` = '$personalid'
```